# In Swift and AVKit, how can i fix my audio playback when i re-run (re-simulate) my app

Tags: swiftui, audio, playback

I successfully record and playback audio (in a consistent audio session) when using one version of my app. Also, when i swipe out of the app fully and reopen, the audio files are still being played. When i re-run the app (without making any changes to the code), the same audio files are not being played in playback UI.

The audio URL is being saved as a string and is being converted to a URL to be played (it definitely exists and is still present). In the re-run, the audio file is still there, but it can't be played.

I have tried using the exact same code again with the same view model and same audio session but it still does not seem to work.

Below is the audio session function i am using consistently

```
    func configureAudioSession() {
    do {
        session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        // Set the category to playAndRecord to enable both playback and recording
        try session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetooth, .allowBluetoothA2DP])
        try session.setActive(true)

        // Add observer for route changes
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(handleRouteChange),
            name: AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification,
            object: nil
        )

        // Add observer for proximity state changes
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(handleProximityStateChange),
            name: UIDevice.proximityStateDidChangeNotification,
            object: nil
        )

        // Enable proximity sensor monitoring
        UIDevice.current.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = true
    } catch {
        print("Audio session configuration error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Latest Edit: I am recording audio on one screen and, once the player stops the recording, it is automatically displayed on the screen in an audio player. Once the user presses submit, this is stored as a String (audioURL converted to string) in firestore.

Then, in another screen, the audio string is retrieved and played in the same audio player as earlier, except now it's stored on a different screen. This is all fine but the issue is that upon re-installation or re-running through XCode, the second screen where the saved URL String is retrieved and played, nothing is playing in the audio player. I have been looking everywhere trying to find the solution but nothing is working.

Below is a simplified version of the code. Keep in mind that audioPlaybackOne[0] is the string array that is an audio URL.

```
VStack {
            let audioURL = audioPlaybackOne[0]
            if let index = audioPlaybackOne.firstIndex(of: audioURL) {
                VStack(spacing: 20){
                    HStack {
                        Text(audioData.formatTime(audioData.currentTime))
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                        
                        Text("\(durations[index])")
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                        
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        Task {
                            durations[index] = try await audioData.fetchAudioDuration(for: URL(string: audioPlaybackOne[index])!)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .opacity(0)
                            .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.12)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button {
                            if audioData.isPlayingArray[index] {
                                audioData.pauseRecording(for: index)
                                audioData.stopTimer(for: index)
                            } else {
                                audioData.audioPlayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: audioURL)!)
                                audioData.playRecording(for: index)
                                audioData.resetAudioOnceComplete(for: index)
                                audioData.startTimer(for: index)
                            }
                            audioData.isPlayingArray[index].toggle()
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: audioData.isPlayingArray[index] ? "pause.fill" : "play.fill")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.045)
                                .foregroundStyle(Color("pausePlay"))
                                .font(.headline)
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.8)
                }
                .padding()
                .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.9, height: geo.size.height * 0.2)
                .background(colorScheme == .dark ? Color(hex: "111111") : Color(hex: "F6F5F5"))
                .cornerRadius(30)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            do {
                audioData.session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
                try audioData.session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [.defaultToSpeaker])
                try audioData.session.setActive(true)
                
                // Enable proximity sensor monitoring when the view appears
                UIDevice.current.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = true
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            audioData.configureAudioSession()
            
            
            if let player = audioData.audioPlayer {
                print("Audio Player: \(player)")
            } else {
                print("Audio Player not initialized.")
            }
            
            // Add an observer at the end of playback
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                audioData.observer,
                selector: #selector(audioData.observer.playerDidFinishPlaying),
                name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                object: nil
            )
            
            // Add observer for proximity state changes
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(audioData.handleProximityStateChange), name: UIDevice.proximityStateDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
            
            // Set the completion block to toggle the UI when playback is complete
            audioData.observer.didPlayToEnd = {
                if let index = audioData.isPlayingArray.firstIndex(of: true) {
                    audioData.isPlayingArray[index] = false
                }
                audioData.isScrubbing = false
            }
        }
        .onDisappear {
            // Disable proximity sensor monitoring when the view is not visible
            UIDevice.current.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = false
            
            // Stop any currently playing audio recordings
            audioData.audioPlayer?.pause()
            currentlyPlayingIndex = nil
            
            for index in 0..<audioData.isPlayingArray.count {
                if audioData.isPlayingArray[index] {
                    audioData.stopTimer(for: index)
                    audioData.isPlayingArray[index] = false
                    audioData.isScrubbing = false
                }
            }
        }
        .onReceive(proximityStateDidChangeNotification) { _ in
            self.isNear = UIDevice.current.proximityState
            
            if isNear {
                // User raised the phone to their ear
                try? audioData.session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [.allowBluetooth, .allowBluetoothA2DP])
            } else {
                // User moved the phone away from their ear
                try? audioData.session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [.defaultToSpeaker])
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to provide code or at least tell us about what is different between the versions.

Comment: Yes sorry for being vague, this is more of an explanation on what the issue is. Let me know if there's anything else i can provide. Thanks for your time.

Comment: “It can’t be played” as in there is an an error or “it isn’t playing” as in the audio stops? The later is expected the former is likely a permissions issue especially in macOS/macCatalyst but again we don’t have enough info. You have to provide an MRE.

Comment: It can't be played as in the audio player is visible (so the audio URL is available) but when you press play nothing happens. Also the duration says "0.0" when it usually indicates how long the audio recording is.